# Android Google Maps supporting intersection in MultiPolygon

Tags: android, google-maps, geojson

I trying to draw a Polygon inside a Polygon hole using a single Feature MultiPolygon, like this:

[image]

However, when I add this GeoJson file on Android the background is not being fulfilled, only the lines are being drawn:

[image]

When I remove the most inner Polygon, it works fine:

[image]

Does the Google Maps SDK somehow supports intersection on MultiPolygons?

Follows the GeoJson file:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-119.443359, 18.646245],
                        [-70.751953, 18.646245],
                        [-70.751953, 46.619261],
                        [-119.443359, 46.619261],
                        [-119.443359, 18.646245]
                    ],
                    [
                        [-105.732422, 25.324167],
                        [-105.732422, 39.164141],
                        [-80.332031, 39.164141],
                        [-80.332031, 25.324167],
                        [-105.732422, 25.324167]
                    ],
                    [
                        [-96.152344, 29.305561],
                        [-96.152344, 35.029996],
                        [-86.132813, 35.029996],
                        [-86.132813, 29.305561],
                        [-96.152344, 29.305561]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) `"MultiPolygon"` with holes should have structure like that:

```
{
    "type": "MultiPolygon", 
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [<coordinates of first polygone>],
            [<coordinates of first hole in first polygone>],
            [<coordinates of second hole in first polygone>],
            ...
            [<coordinates of last hole in first polygone>]
        ], 
        ...
        [
            [<coordinates of last polygone>],
            [<coordinates of first hole in last polygone>],
            [<coordinates of second hole in last polygone>],
            ...
            [<coordinates of last hole in last polygone>]
        ]
    ]
}
```

So, exactly for yours case "most inner Polygon" should be moved one level up and GeoJSON should be like that:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        [-119.443359, 18.646245],
                        [-70.751953, 18.646245],
                        [-70.751953, 46.619261],
                        [-119.443359, 46.619261],
                        [-119.443359, 18.646245]
                    ],
                    [
                        [-105.732422, 25.324167],
                        [-105.732422, 39.164141],
                        [-80.332031, 39.164141],
                        [-80.332031, 25.324167],
                        [-105.732422, 25.324167]
                    ]
                ],
                [
                   [
                        [-96.152344, 29.305561],
                        [-96.152344, 35.029996],
                        [-86.132813, 35.029996],
                        [-86.132813, 29.305561],
                        [-96.152344, 29.305561]
                    ]
                  ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

The result in that case is:

[image]